# How to redirect print command output either to a file or to screen based on an if statement condition in Python?

Tags: python

I have a simple code that prints a string. I'd like to implement an if condition that if the value was true it will print the string to a file, otherwise it will print it to screen.

Is there any way to do this without having 2 identical print commands (one to print to file and another one to display)?
Something similar to the below snippet:

```
filename = 'log.txt'
if SomeCondition == TRUE:
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        print("Hello World!", file=f)
else:
    print("Hello World!") #Is there a way to avoid duplicating the print statment?
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```py
filename = 'log.txt'
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    print("Hello World!", file=[None, f][condition])
```